# Unable to parse object sent from server on client side in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript

I am writing a javascript program in Typescript based on backboneJS, in which the server sends an object with structured data to the client which I am not able to successfully parse in the client. The code is an implementation of a typescript interface which accepts the data or error from the server for a call made for the client.

The Typescript interface is this:

```
interface PersistenceOptions {
        url?: string;
        beforeSend?: (jqxhr: JQueryXHR) => void;
        success?: (modelOrCollection?: any, response?: any, options?: any) => void;
        error?: (modelOrCollection?: any, jqxhr?: JQueryXHR, options?: any) => void;
    }
```

Here is the code for the success functions which is unable to render the "response" data

```
success:function(modelOrCollection?: any, response?: any, options?: any){
                $holder.append(response.toString());
            }
```

Here's what the actual object looks like when you make a rest call:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "answer": "I like the device",
    "type": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "answer": "Im not sure if I want it",
    "type": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "answer": "This is a great device",
    "type": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "answer": "I like it but its expensive",
    "type": 0
  }
]
```

The actual output on the screen looks like this:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I want to be able to parse and programatically manipulate the output. Not sure how.

(I also want to know what kind of an object is this and how to create new ones.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't output a Object directly. You have to loop the properties of the object and because the objects are in an array, you have to go through the array. You can do that with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
success: function (modelOrCollection ? : any, response ? : any, options ? : any) {
    response.map(function (object) {
        for (prop in object) {
            $holder.append(prop + ':' + object[prop] + '<br/>');
        }
    });
}
```

<kbd>[JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/A8yLw/)</kbd>

Comment: By the way, it would really nice if you could answer one more question. What type of object is this and how can you instantiate a new one and then add/modify/delete data into it - both on the server and client?

Comment: [Objects in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) and [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). I hope these links will help you further.